# Pre-fill edittext with informations from database

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i'm working on an android chat application, i've a webservice wich manipulate an sql server data base and the mobile app seperated, in mobile app, i've fragments (home,edit profile,logout), in the edit profile fragment i want the edittext to be pre-filled with informations of the owner of the account from database, so i send user_login from the app to the webservice and the webservice return a user object so i can take his informations to pre-fill the edittext, so here's the code of the webservice :

```
public synchronized void modifierProfil(String login) {
        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * from Utilisateurs where login = '" + login + "';");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
                user.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setDateNaissance(rs.getDate("dateNaissance"));
                user.setNomPersonne(rs.getString("nomPersonne"));
                user.setPrenomPersonne(rs.getString("prenomPersonne"));
                user.setNumTelephone(rs.getInt("numTelephone"));
                user.setPhotoProfil(rs.getString("photoProfil"));
                user.setSexe(rs.getString("sexe"));
                env.setObjet(user);
                reponse = "ok";
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            reponse = "erreur";
        } finally {
            try {
                env.setAction(reponse);
                TCPConnection.send(env, acceptedSocket);
                acceptedSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
            }
        }
    }
```

and here's the profile fragment code :

```
public static class ProfilFrag extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView photoProfil;
    EditText username, email, password, nomPrenom;
    String UserName, Pwd, Email;
    Button submit, changerPhoto;

    ModifierProgress connection ;

    private DatagramPacket sendP;
    private DatagramPacket receiveP;
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private int serverPort;
    private String send;
    public static String serverIP;
    private byte data2[];
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    String rdata;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        connection = new ModifierProgress();
        connection.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        username = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
        email = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
        password = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
        nomPrenom = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edNomPrenom);
        submit = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        photoProfil = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.largeThumbnailView);
        changerPhoto = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnChanger);

        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        changerPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

        data2 = new byte[100];
        serverPort = 6500;

        settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.current);

        serverIP = settings.getString("serverIP", Connection.ipServer);
        Log.i("Login", serverIP);
        }

    private class ModifierProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ***String un*** = username.getText().toString();
                Envoyable env = new Envoyable(un, "modifierProfil");
                Socket sock = TCPConnection.send(env);
                Log.i("modifierProfil", "modification Profil");
                env = (Envoyable) TCPConnection.Receive(sock);
                String rep = env.getAction();
                Log.i("modifierProfil", "received msg from server: " + rep);
                publishProgress("modification");
                if (rep.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                    Utilisateur m = (Utilisateur) env.getObjet();
                    Utils.Helper.saveUser(settings, "m", m);
                    getActivity().finish();
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(photoProfil, m.getPhotoProfil());
                    username.setText(m.getLogin());
                    password.setText(m.getPassword());
                    email.setText(m.getEmail());
                }
                else if (rep.equalsIgnoreCase("erreur")){
                    publishProgress("err");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Une erreur s'est produite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the attribute "un" gets always a null value and even if put directly a value on it the edittext are not prefilled.
So where's the problem ?

Comment: Maybe do you have an hint enabled in your xml?!

Comment: no i haven't any hint enabled

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

> connection.execute();

in OnCreate Method dont call their. Call it after finding ids of all edittext and buttons.